# Google Docs Embed: Have it crawled and indexed by Google

Tags: indexing, embed, google-docs, web-crawler

On our website, we have loads of PDFs and Word Docs displayed via the Google Docs Embed widget:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://our-url.com/view=file.doc&embedded=true" width="xxx" height="xxx" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Is there any way to make Google actually crawl and index the content of these boxes?

It would help our ranking tremendously, seeing that due to the nature of our website, our entire unique content is displayed in the Google Docs window... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

It looks like your links will be crawled by Google. [Do robots crawl iframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453296/do-robots-crawl-iframes) 
(Also, if you want Google to index the content of the file, make the sharing setting (on the Google Doc) "Public on the web").

Secondly, register your website on [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home). This will basically ensure that Google knows about your site, and you can check on how often Google crawls your site, etc. etc. You have to confirm that you're the owner of the domain though, so you'll need to have access to nameserver management (I believe).

Comment: How about the iFrame from App Script, example:
`function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}`

Do we need configure anything on Google Search Console or robot.txt?

Comment: @AntonioOoi found an answer to your question after this time ?

Comment: @user305883: Nope, but I believe iFrame contents that are not on your Search Console's domain (or property) will not be regarded by Google as part of your site content -- just a guess though.